# How to restore cache to its initial state

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I use SSR to rehydrate the cache with initial state from the server

```
const cache = new InMemoryCache().restore(window.__APOLLO_STATE__)
```

Few mutations later, I need to **hard reset the cache to its initial state**. I naively tried to keep the initial store in component state and pass it to `client.restore`

```
componentDidMount () {
  this.setState({
    initState: this.props.client.extract()
  })
}

// When I need to reset, I'd call this method...
handleCacheReset () {
  this.props.client.restore( this.state.initState )
}
```

but it didn't work. Since I'm also using using `apollo-link-state`, I thought if I keep the cache data as defaults, maybe then I can write them when `client.resetStore` is called

```
const cache = new InMemoryCache().restore(window.__APOLLO_STATE__)
const link = withClientState({ cache })
const client = new ApolloClient({
  link, cache,
  defaults: cache.data.data
})
client.onResetStore(link.writeDefaults)

// ...when it's time to reset the store
client.resetStore()
```

But I only get `Missing field ... in {}` errors and no data gets written to the store. Worse, I can't use `client.writeData` since I only have the initial `window.__APOLLO_STATE__`. If only I could read the entire cache data, then it might be plausible, but there doesn't seem to be a `readData` method.

#### Is there a way to programmatically restore the cache to its original state?

So far the only workaround I see is re-creating the entire `ApolloClient` and forcefully re-rendering the tree, which is expensive and inefficient. Thoughts?

P.S. Asked this on [GitHub](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/3670), but they closed it with no answer.

Comment: It used to be a `readFragment` and `readQuery` method on the `client`. Have you check for that ?

Answer (score 0):

Is this on web or mobile? I haven't been able to solve this myself, but in thinking about [apollo-cache-persist](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-cache-persist), you could theoretically save states of your cache to local storage and restore them to your cache at a later time.

Comment: Web. I'll give `apollo-cache-persist` a try.

Answer (score 0):

`this.props.client.extract()` returns directly the cache object not a copy :
https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/master/packages/apollo-cache-inmemory/src/depTrackingCache.ts#L23

If you want to keep the original state, you can do :

`initState: {...this.props.client.extract()}`